# JAXB : Map< String, (Map<Object,List<Object>>) >

Tags: jaxb, jaxb2

i'm working on some web services and i'm trying to send an object having the following structure : Map< String, (Map>) >
the problem is that jaxb fail to marshall that object
can anybody suggest some way to make this work

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `XmlAdapter` for this use case.  An `XmlAdapter` enables you to convert an unmappable object into a mappable one for the purposes of marshalling and unmarshalling.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html

Comment: tahanks @Blaise what i'm thinking to do is to use generic mappable map<object,object> and list<object,object>, and construct my object using them. it seems that this does not work for me. i'm not sure if that is possible or not ??.